# How to remove line column from Airline section z?

Tags: plugin-airline

I am okay with rest of the section z but I want to remove `㏑ :  1` from the default section z configuration because I think it's not useful for me and takes up the space unnecessarily. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inspect the default value of `g:airline_section_z` by issuing `:echo g:airline_section_z`. Note, this includes already the bold accents.

In airline, the default is set to:

```
  if airline#util#winwidth() > 79
    let g:airline_section_z = airline#section#create(['windowswap', 'obsession', '%3p%%'.spc, 'linenr', 'maxlinenr', spc.':%3v'])
  else
    let g:airline_section_z = airline#section#create(['%3p%%'.spc, 'linenr',  ':%3v'])
  endif
```

(where `spc` means `Space`, and it depends on the terminal width, which parts are included).

So you can customize this by setting the `g:airline_section_z` variable. Unfortunately, since by the time the vimrc file is read, vim-airline has not been read yet, so you need to postpone configuring the variable until vim-airline has been read. For that purpose, vim-airline exposes the `AirlineAfterInit` autocommand event.

Putting it all together, you would want to configure your section like this in your .vimrc:

```
au User AirlineAfterInit  :let g:airline_section_z = airline#section#create(['windowswap', 'obsession', '%3p%%', 'maxlinenr', ' :%3v'])
```

or for a very simple one:

```
au User AirlineAfterInit  :let g:airline_section_z = airline#section#create(['%3p%% %L:%3v'])
```

For the meanings of the `%-expandos` have a look at [:h 'statusline'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#'statusline')

Comment: This does not seem up-do-date anymore, because I get `E121: Undefined variable: spc
E116: Invalid arguments for function airline#section#create
E15: Invalid expression: airline#section#create(['windowswap', 'obsession', '%3p%%'.spc, 'linenr', 'maxlinenr', spc.':%3v'])` when I copy what is claimed to be default in this answer. Furthermore, if I use the `echo` command, in my case `g:airline_section_z` is set to: `%p%% %#__accent_bold#%{g:airline_symbols.linenr}%l%#__restore__#%#__accent_bold#/%L%{g:airline_symbols.maxlinenr}%#__restore__#:%v`

Comment: @PhilippLudwig the variable `spc` is not defined. You need to define it before using it.